# Launching Android Applications through Unity / Java plugins

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to connect my Unity project to Java via plugin in order to launch another application, and have been unsuccessful with attempts to do so.

Unity (C#):

```
public void AndroidCallNonStatic() {
    using (AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
        using (AndroidJavaObject activity = javaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) {
            object[] targs = new object[1] { "org.mozilla.firefox" };
            activity.Call("nonStaticMethod", targs);
        }
    }
}
```

Java (Android):

```
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
public class Main extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    public static Context mContext;
    public static PackageManager mManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            mContext = this;
            mManager = getPackageManager();
    }

    public void nonStaticMethod(String s)
    {
            Log.d("TAG","nonStatic method was called");
            launchApp(s);
    }

    public static void StaticMethod(String s)
    {
            Log.d("TAG","Static method was called " + s);
            launchApp(s);
    }

    public void launchApp(String packageName)
    {
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (intent != null)
        {
            // Activity was found, launch new app
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            // Activity not found. Send user to market
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+packageName));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

}

Can anyone help me out with this? I've exhausted the extent of my Android/Unity knowledge and can't understand why it's not working. My thoughts are that it has something to do with the package name.

Comment: Is Unity giving you some error, or is it just plain not finding the plugin?

Comment: @dudeprgm Unity is giving me an error for a null pointer exception, but the plugin itself IS being found. I've a feeling that the reason this isn't launching is because I need to know the actual name of the activity to launch. I'm running a few more tests to see if I can launch Google's camera or gallery, which are more easily integrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch an Android application from Unity directly in C#:

```
public void LaunchApp(String packageName)
{
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer;
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity;
    AndroidJavaObject packageManager;
    AndroidJavaObject launchIntent;

    unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    packageManager = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
    launchIntent = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", packageName);
    currentActivity.Call("startActivity", launchIntent);
}
```